# WiX bind property (or any other custom data) into bundle

Tags: wix

I want to define some static information in my WiX package, doesn't matter how - a `Property`, a `WixVariable` or even a preprocessor `<?define?>` variable.

After that, I want to pass that piece of information into the Bundle project, maybe with Burn's [Binder Variables](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/overview/light.html). How can I do it?

I need something like:

```
!(bind.myDefinedInformation.PackageID)
```

Answer (score 0):

To pass variables to what I assume, in your case, is a Custom BootstrapperApplication you can add a Variable sub-element to your Bundle element inside Bundle.wxs, e.g.:

```
<Variable Name="USERID" Type="string" Value="user" bal:Overridable="yes" />
```

Note: with this code you need to add:

```
 xmlns:bal="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/BalExtension"
```

to your Wix header.
In your BootstrapperApplication code you can the reference this variable like so:

```
var user = Engine.StringVariables["USERID"];
```

Or even set it like so:

```
Engine.StringVariables["USERID"] = "test";
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm seeking for a way to pass custom information from MSI package (built in WiX) to a bundle, and not yet from bundle to the Custom Bootstrapper. And, by the way, I think it could be done with Binder Variables, but I don't really know.

Comment: Sorry I couldn't help. There is an MsiProperty sub element to MsiPackage which maps to a public property in the MSI. Just food for thought not sure if it helps.